# Create class property dynamically/programmatically

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

I am looking to do something similar to the way CodeIgniter's `load` object works.  You can instantiate a class, and in this example, a model, by using:

`$this->load->model('some_model', 'custom_name')`

The model `some_model` is now accessible via `$this->custom_name`.  Does this make use of `__set()` and `__get()` or is it something entirely different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, codeigniter does not use getters/setters. Assuming that `$this` is available in context:

```
$dynamic_class_name    = 'some_model';
$dynamic_property_name = 'custom_name';

$this->$dynamic_property_name = new $dynamic_class_name;
```

You're done, you can also pass dynamic constructor params when instantiating.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a reflection class.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php

```
<?php

    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($class_name);
    $this->$class_name = $reflection->newInstanceArgs($params);
```